how to resolve the error occurring in app/build.gradle or project/build.gradle
app/build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' // Ensure this version matches your setup
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Ensure this line is within the plugins block
    id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34 // Adjust as necessary
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.instagram"
        minSdkVersion 21 // Adjust as necessary
        targetSdkVersion 34 // Adjust as necessary
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    // Add other Firebase or dependencies as needed
}

project/build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2' // or your current Gradle version
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' // add the Google services Gradle plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Error
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Hussain\applications\instagram\android\app\build.gradle' line: 36

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
   > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).

I was getting an error that told that in android section there is something wrong with the Android Manifest.xml file and i have to transfer all the code, pubspec.yaml file, and integrate all the dependencies and plugins in both app and project level gradle files and to put the
google-services.json

as instructed by the firebase
so,
I shifted the code to a newly created application and on running the project this error showed up a tried to resolve it through ChatGPT but nothing worked these gradle files are copy pasted from ChatGPT prompt but it is still not working. The application is successfully running on the web but not android.

For 1st failure:
In your project-level build.gradle you have defined this:
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Android Studio's Gradle wrapper already has a clean task defined, so there's no need to re-define it. Remove it and try again.
For 2nd failure:
compileSdkVersion is deprecated.
For more info about compileSdkVersion
compileSdkVersion replaced by compileSdk
Instead of writing compileSdkVersion try compileSdk like this:
android {
    namespace = "com.example.instagram"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.instagram"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

